# How to add google analytics tracking with angular universal ssr

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I was working on an angular universal SSR application and wanted to add Google Analytics tracking for page views but couldn't get it to work.

Most packages that are out there that I tried did not work with SSR because they tried to access the window/document directly.

Eventually I ended up with a fairly basic solution that I wanted to share.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By importing isPlatformBrowser you can specify code that you only want to execute on the client. Then you can append the appropriate script tags for google analytics tracking.

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ElementRef, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-analytics-gtag',
  template: '',
})
export class GoogleAnalyticsGTagComponent {
  trackingCode = environment.googleAnalyticsTrackingCode;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private readonly platformId: Object,
    private readonly renderer: Renderer2,
    private readonly el: ElementRef,
  ) {
    // BROWSER
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const script = this.renderer.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
      script.src = `//www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${this.trackingCode}`;
      script.async = true;
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, script);

      const script2 = this.renderer.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
      const scriptBody = this.renderer.createText(`
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
          dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', '${this.trackingCode}');
      `);
      this.renderer.appendChild(script2, scriptBody);
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, script2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @AbijithAjayan - I created this component and then added `<app-google-analytics-gtag></app-google-analytics-gtag>` to my app.component.html

Comment: Do you need to add <app-google-analytics-gtag></app-google-analytics-gtag> to each component html, or just in app.component.html?  For some reason, analytics is only recognizing the components where the tag is present, which means I would need to add it to each route/component.

Comment: @dc922 you need to add it only to the app.component

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using Document based on Cris Putnam answer:

```
import { DOCUMENT, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-analytics-gtag',
  template: '',
})
export class GoogleAnalyticsGTagComponent {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private readonly platformId: Object,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) {
    const gaTrackId = this.configService.getGoogleAnalyticsTrackId();
    const debugMode = this.configService.getGoogleAnalyticsDebugMode();
    // BROWSER
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const scriptGtag = this.document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
      scriptGtag.src = `//www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${gaTrackId}`;
      scriptGtag.async = true;
      this.document.head.appendChild(scriptGtag);

      const scriptInit = this.document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
      const scriptBody = this.document.createTextNode(`
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() {
          dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '${gaTrackId}', { debug_mode: ${debugMode} });
      `);

      scriptInit.appendChild(scriptBody);
      this.document.head.appendChild(scriptInit);
    }
  }
}
```